# regular expression for multiple IP address with different range, need to pharse specific IP

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for regular expression for validation IP address for different mask

Example:

```
IP = [10.0.1.1 , 192.168.1.1, 200.1.1.1]
```

among these IP's I need to parse(find) IP for `10.0.1.1` only .

Comment: you should provide more information. You want it to trigger only on ip with this range `2.1.1.1` ( each number here is length of that part)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the python `ip_address` library found here (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

What you can try to do is parse them all into a list of objects

```
result = list(map(ipaddress.ip_address, IP))
# then we filter depending on the bitmask here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex to match exactly that number of digits in ip is following:

`\d{2}(\.\d{1}){3}`

[Pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%7B2%7D(%5C.%5Cd%7B1%7D)%7B3%7D&test_string=10.1.1.1%0A192.168.1.1&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) for that regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You should provide little more information on which pattern you are looking in ip address?

Basis on your current need you can use this :

```
import re
pattern=r'\d{2}(?=[.]).\d{1}([.]\d{1})(\1)'

string="IP = [10.0.1.1 , 192.168.1.1, 200.1.1.1]"

match=re.search(pattern,string)

print(match.group())
```

output:

```
10.0.1.1
```